Rig rendering as black in Cycles
I have put together a basic scene with a light source casting onto a rig copied over from another file. The textures appear normal in texture preview and in EEVEE, but when rendering in Cycles the rig turns out black.
I have no idea as to how this could be happening as I am relatively new to Blender.
Here is my scene and a picture: https://filebin.net/6o97trb0w3466xkc


Pure black in cycles usually means the surface is giving no light response.  The shader output might be set to eevee only, or you might just try connecting the output noodle again to rebuild the node graph.

The rigged character appears dark because of flipped normals generated by Solidify modifier. If you disable modifier it is rendered fine, but ...
... in your case the solidify modifier is used to generate flipped faces for a reason to be used as trick to render outline stroke. This "trick" is based on "Backface Culling" feature, that is available for Eevee, but not for Cycles render engine.
You would have to use different technique to generate a stroke in Cycles ... like Freestyle described in gandalf3's answer.
